# Trying to reference a class after the page loads with colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I have a list of links that are generated after a button click, so obviously, these links are rendered after the page and the jquery has already loaded. The links look like:

```
<a class="person" href="xxxxxx.xxx"</a>
```

The jquery I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".person").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
};
```

Assigning that class to a link on the page that renders with the page works correctly. How can I use the jquery to reference tags, classes, etc. that load afterwards?

Comment: Are you looking to ref an individual person >?

Comment: After the button click event, run the colorbox code. `.person` does not exist in the document load, but after said button click, so you have to trigger the `colorbox` function AFTER the button has been clicked, and the elements are applied to the dom

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear on that. The links are search results of people that are generated when the criteria are searched for. Ultimately, each ref will point to a separate page (generated in the lightbox) that shows more information about the person. Right now, I was just trying to do it with a general link like weather.com. The text of the link is the person's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe im missing something.. But cant you put the .ready function into its own callable function ?

So for example:

```
var reloadPeople = function(){
    $(".person").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
}
```

Then everytime one is added after the document load you can run the function

`reloadPeople();`

Im not familiar with colourbox but javascript is the same all round! :)